# How to get multiple datasets after calling db stored procedure in Mule

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

A Mule application is calling a stored procedure like this: `call sp("email","ispresent","id")`. This procedure returns two data sets; one dataset for user details and another for college details. Below I'm attaching an example response which we need to get after calling the procedure.

```
{
 "userdetails": {
     "emailId":""abc@gmail.com",
     "useris":"20"
      "ispresent":0,
      "collegedetails":{
         "collegeName":"VV",
          "collegeid":"12"
  }
}
```

Comment: The example output that you have provided is not a valid JSON. Can you update with the correct one?

Comment: You mean calling a stored procedure from a *Mule* application, right? MuleSoft is the company name. What are the versions of Mule, DB connector, which database is used?

Comment: @HarshankBansal please find the correct json { "userdetails": { "emailId":""abc@gmail.com", "useris":"20" "ispresent":0, "collegedetails":{ "collegeName":"VV", "collegeid":"12" } }}

Comment: @aled yes exactly calling stored procedure from mule application. version i am using for db connector is 1.5.4 database we are using is IBM DB2

Comment: the below is the structure i used and getting the error ""java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Record cannot be mapped as it contains multiple columns with the same label. Define column aliases to solve this problem
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Record cannot be mapped as it contains multiple columns with the same label. Define column aliases to solve this problem"

Comment: Do you mean that the payload returned by the stored procedure is directly JSON instead of a result set? That seems strange. Is that a feature of DB2? And please edit your question to add the details. People should not need to read all the comments to understand the issue.